# Trying to make my program deliverable to a windows 10 environment

Tags: python, windows

So a bit of a broad question here.

Basically, I have designed and built a program that runs on my machine, using Python. The problem is when I turn it into an exe and try to run it on another windows 10 machine, it doesn't work.

The reason is because on my machine, I have python installed, python VLC installed and also the VLC player. Is the issue that I somehow need to package these programs (dependencies? Yes, I'm a noob) into the installation wizard or?

Would love some advice on what to do here as I'm working on a sentimental project for someone and it's really frustrating that I can't get it to work lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python-vlc, you do need VLC installed. I do not know of a way to package vlc into a python exe. I would recommend looking into independent modules, that are not just python wrappers.

Edit:

You could use the sound functions from the pygame library:

```
import pygame.mixer

SOUND_FILE = 'file_path_here'

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(SOUND_FILE)
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=1626) # 1626 seconds from beginning

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.wait()
```

Comment: See, I'm gonna be honest, this is all new to me. I really am a noob and what you just said makes very little sense to me. Usually I would look this up online or watch videos or something, but there doesn't seem to even be a good starting point.

Comment: python-vlc is just a python wrapper. This means that it is just basically a compatibility layer. Confusing terms aside, try to look for other modules that do not depend on installing software. :)  Comment if you do not understand

Comment: Yea I do kind of get what you're saying. Like, it is just an outline of the main software and it requires the main software to run. That probably complicates delivery a lot for obvious reasons. I'm trying to play a song with the program at a certain point. Maybe there are other ways to implement this without vlc ?

Comment: :) edited answer with code, just use pygame instead of python-vlc

Comment: Hey. I am having trouble with this. It's weird because what I want to happen is I play the sound and then make a turtle graphic come on the screen and draw something. When I do this, I have to press the graphic with my mouse otherwise the sound does not play? Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Check your code :) or maybe try googling another way :)

Comment: I solved the issue by using mouse clicks to click the graphic for me :D The only thing I'm having an issue with now is my pyinstaller exe won't run :( thanks for the help, I really appreciate it

Comment: try running the exe from the command line, and you might see the error :)  Pls mark my answer as the correct one (checkmark) if it answered your question

Comment: did I not do it already? The green mark with the large 1?

Comment: oh, yes you did, did not see :), are there any errors when running from cmd?

Comment: navigate to exe, and run: `.\exe_name.exe`

Comment: I ran it in cmd and get an error. I made a question about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080051/python-based-exe-throwing-error-at-cmd-pynput-module

Answer (score 0):

You should not bundle VLC for many reasons even if that technically doable. The cleanest solution would be to check if VLC or the VLC player is installed and tell user to install it first if it's missing.

Comment: say you used 64 bit python, and the person install 32 bit vlc or the other way around. 
What would you do then?

Comment: Same thing. Check what is installed, warn if I detect incompatibility or potential problems, warn on first use if I cannot detect that - anything, but installing 3rd party apps